# Syntax error when preparing statements in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepare, mysql-5.6

In a game for Android users can login via Google+, Facebook, Twitter:

[image: app screenshot]

When the app connects to the MySQL/PHP backend it sends a list of the social ids and I store them as **sid** column in **social** table:

```
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sid    | varchar(180)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| given  | varchar(180)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| family | varchar(180)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city   | varchar(180)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| photo  | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| stamp  | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| uid    | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

In the other table called **users** I keep autoincremented user ids as **uid** column and use it to track their games and achievements (column **medals**):

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| stamp         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| banned_until  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| banned_reason | varchar(180) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| medals        | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In my PHP login script I try to *merge* social accounts whenever possible -

by taking all received **sids**, finding the corresponding **uids** and then taking the *lowest* found **uid** and updating the records in the **social** table to use that lowest **uid**.

This works well in PHP, but now I am trying to move the merging functionality into a MySQL stored procedure with 2 [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```
delimiter $$$

drop procedure if exists merge_users;
create procedure merge_users(IN in_sids varchar(255))
begin
        declare sql_1 varchar(255);
        declare sql_2 varchar(255);
        declare out_uid varchar(255);

        set sql_1 = concat('select min(uid) into out_uid from social where sid in (', in_sids, ')');
        prepare sth_1 from sql_1;
        execute sth_1;
        deallocate prepare sth_1;

        IF found_rows() > 0 THEN

                set sql_2 = concat('update social set uid=', out_uid, ' where sid in (', in_sids, ')');
                prepare sth_2 from sql_2;
                execute sth_2;
                deallocate prepare sth_2;
        ELSE
                insert into users(created, stamp, medals, green, red)
                values (unix_timestamp(), unix_timestamp(), 0, 0, 0);

                select last_insert_uid() into out_uid;

        END IF;

        select out_uid;
end
$$$
```

Unfortunately, the above code prints the syntax error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
                    check the manual that
        execute sth_1;
        deallocate prepare sth_1;

        IF foun' at line 8
```

Comment: `PREPARE stmt_name FROM preparable_stmt`. `preparable_stmt` is either a string literal or a user variable ([9.4 User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)) that contains the text of the SQL statement. See [13.5.1 PREPARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html).

Comment: Yes (+1) and that is why I construct a string using `concat`. For example: `select min(uid) into out_uid from social where sid in ('dhsjhdsjhsjh')`

Comment: Remember to use `@out_uid` instead of `out_uid`.

Comment: Are you sure? The syntax error is still there even with `@out_uid`.

Comment: See [SQL Fiddle test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/41835).

Comment: Yes, but what happens, when you put that code in a SP body? Unfortunately, the SQL Fiddle server does not work well for me.

Comment: See [SQL Fiddle test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a073e9/1).